# Line follower overshoot

Tags: robotics

The line follower robot reaches the top of inclined surface and then goes to plane surface at that time sensor distance from ground increases and robot overshoots.

What is the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Calibrate the sensors so that it does works even when the robot reaches on top of the inclined surface(i.e the robot reaches the peak and the distance between the sensor and the ground increases).